# PHP mysql search queries

Tags: php, mysql, search, indexing

I'm trying to create a search engine for an inventory based site.  The issue is that I have information inside bbtags (like in `[b]test[/b] sentence`, the `test` should be valued at `3`, whereas `sentence` should be valued at `1`).

Here is an example of an index:
`My test sentence, my my` (has a SKU of `TST-DFS`)
The Database:

```
|Product|  word  |relevancy|
|   1   |   my   |    3    |
|   1   |  test  |    1    |
|   1   |sentence|    1    |
|   1   | TST-DFS|    10   |
```

But how would I match `TST-DFS` if the user typed in `TST DFS`? I would like that SKU to have a relevancy of say `8`, instead of the full `10`..

I have heard that the FULL TEXT search feature in MySQL would help, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it.  I would like to avoid things like UNIONS, and to keep the query as optimized as possible.

Any help with coming up with a good system for this would be great.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Can't you use MySQL's `FULLTEXT` capabilities, or is that what you mean when you say "index"?

Comment: The problem is I have a lot of information that is important, but MySQL's FULLTEXT doesn't know it is important (like sku numbers, product name, and other certain words).  So I'm indexing each word in each product, and I don't believe MySQL's FULLTEXT would help me search through each of the rows.

Comment: Oh right. As far as I can see, no, `FULLTEXT` wouldn't be useful at all. A shame really, seeing as it's a wonderful part of MySQL.

Comment: It really is, I wish it helped search word indexes as well.  I might be able to use it for the content pages though (about us, contact, etc.), that would be nice.

Comment: You could write a custom [full text parser plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-text-plugins.html) to do what you want.

Comment: That's very interesting, but I don't think I would have the system level access needed to install the plugin, nor the expertise to write it in what looks like C or C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how would I match TST-DFS if the user typed in TST DFS?
>   I would like that SKU to have a relevancy of say 8, instead of the full 10..

If I got the question right, the answer is actually easy.
Well, if you *forge* your query a little before sending it to mysql.

Ok, let's say we have `$query` and it contains `TST-DFS`.

Are we gonna focus on **word spans**?
I suppose we should, *as most search engines do*, so:

```
$ok=preg_match_all('#\w+#',$query,$m);
```

Now *if that pattern matched*... `$m[0]` contains the **list of words** in `$query`.
This can be fine-tuned to your SKU, but matching against full words in a AND fashion is pretty much what the user presumes is happening. (as it happens over google and yahoo)

Then we need to cook a `$expr` expression that *will be injected* into our final query.

```
if(!$ok) { // the search string is non-alphanumeric
  $expr="false";
} else {   // the search contains words that are no in $m[0]
  $expr='';
  foreach($m[0] as $word) {
    if($expr)
      $expr.=" AND ";  // put an AND inbetween "LIKE" subexpressions
    $s_word=addslashes($word); // I put a s_ to remind me the variable
                                 // is safe to include in a SQL statement, that's me 
    $expr.="word LIKE '%$s_word%'"; 
  }
}
```

Now `$expr` should look like `"words LIKE '%TST%' AND words LIKE '%DFS%'"`

With that value, we can build the final query:

```
$s_expr="($expr)";
$s_query=addslashes($query);

$s_fullquery=
"SELECT (Product,word,if((word LIKE '$s_query'),relevancy,relevancy-2) as relevancy) ".
"FROM some_index ".
"WHERE word LIKE '$s_query' OR $s_expr";
```

Which shall read, for "TST-DFS":

```
SELECT (Product,word,if((word LIKE 'TST-DFS'),relevancy,relevancy-2) as relevancy)
FROM some_index
WHERE word LIKE 'TST-DFS' OR (word LIKE '%TST%' AND word LIKE '%DFS%')
```

As you can see, in the first `SELECT` line, **if the match is partial, mysql will return relevancy-2**

In the third one, the `WHERE` clause, **if the full match fails, `$s_expr`**, **the partial match query we cooked in advance**, is tried instead.

Comment: corrected. my logic was wrong. 

**Now** `$expr` should look like `words LIKE '%TST%' AND words LIKE '%DFS%'`

Comment: So where are you getting the `relevancy` column?

Comment: nevermind about the above, how would this work with a multi-word query though?  It seems it's comparing itself to either be the word perfectly, or contain all the subwords, am I correct about this?

Comment: ...anyway your question about the relevancy (that was pretty hard to answer as I wasn't sure we where on the same page) made me think you may want to sort results on relevancy directly in mysql and for that you will need a relevancy alias `as relevancy` that I edited in so that you can then add a `sort by relevancy`

Comment: ...and yes, a multi-word query would match on all the words.

Comment: I had to modify it to work with multi-word queries, but I did use this one the most, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I like to lower case everything and strip out special characters (like in a phone number or credit card I take everything out on both sides that isn't a number)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to create your own FTS solution, you could try to fit the MySQL FTS engine to your requirements.  What I've seen done is create a new table to store your FTS data.  Create a column for each different piece of data that you want to have a different relevance.  For your sku field you could store the raw sku, with spaces, underscores, hyphens and any other special character intact.  Then store a stripped down version with all these things removed.  You may also want to store a version with leading zeros removed, as people often leave things like that out. You can store all these variations in the same column.  Store your product name in another column, and the product description in another column.  Create a separate index on each column.  Then when you do your search, you can search each column individually, and multiply the rank of the results based on how important you think that column is. So you could multiply sku results by 10, title by 5 and leave description results as is. You may have to do a little experimentation to get the results you want, but it may ultimately be simpler than creating your own index.

Comment: I have bbcode that surrounds subtitles in the description.  could I take everything between the bbcodes, and merge all the worlds together (with spaces between them) in one column, and multiply that column by say 3?  Also, could you give a simple example of using fulltext with different multipliers?

Comment: If you'd be willing to expand on your answer, I'd be happy to add a bounty to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a keywords table.  Something along the lines of:

```
integer keywordId (autoincrement) | varchar keyword | int pointValue
```

Assign all possible keywords, skus, etc, into this table. Create another table, a post-keywords bridge, (assuming `postId` is the id you've assigned in your original table) along the lines of:

```
integer keywordId | integer postId
```

Once you have this, you can easily add keywords to each post as it is interested.  To calculate total point value for a given post, a query such as the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT sum(pointValue) FROM keywordPostsBridge kpb 
JOIN keywords k ON k.keywordId = kpb.keywordId
WHERE kpb.postId = YOUR_INTENDED_POST
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is quite straightforward unless I missed something.

Basically run two search, one is exact match, the other is like match or regex match.

Join two resultsets together, like match left join exact match. Then for example:

```
final_relevancy = (IFNULL(like_relevancy, 0) + IFNULL(exact_relevancy, 0) * 3) / 4
```

I didn't try this myself though. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column that is stripped of all special character's, misspellings, and then upcased (or create a function that compares on text that has been stripped and upcased).  That way your relevancy will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
q and q1 - you table
this query takes too much resources,
make from it update-query ( scheduled task or call it on_save if you develop new system )
*/
SELECT
       CASE
              WHEN word NOT REGEXP "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
                     /*many replace with junk characters
                     or create custom function
                     or if you have full db access install his https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp
                     */
              THEN REPLACE(REPLACE( word, '-', ' ' ), '#', ' ')
              ELSE word
       END word ,
       CASE
              WHEN word NOT REGEXP "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
              THEN 8
              ELSE relevancy
       END           relevancy
FROM   ( SELECT 'my' word,
               3     relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'test' word,
              1      relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'sentence' word,
              1          relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'TST-DFS' word,
              10 relevancy
       )
       q

UNION

SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT 'my' word,
               3     relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'test' word,
              1      relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'sentence' word,
              1          relevancy

       UNION

       SELECT 'TST-DFS' word,
              10 relevancy
       )
       q1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it is a page coading where query result shows

**i can not use functions by use them work are more easier**

 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
//author S_A_KHAN
//date 10/02/2013
 $dbcoonect=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root");
 if (!$dbcoonect)
{
die ('unable to connect'.mysqli_error());
 }
 else
 {
 echo "connection successfully <br>";

 }
 $data_base=mysql_select_db("connect",$dbcoonect);


 if ($data_base==FALSE){

die ('unable to connect'.mysqli_error($dbcoonect));
  }
 else
  {
echo "connection successfully done<br>";
    ***$SQLString = "select * from user where id= " . $_GET["search"] . "";
$QueryResult=mysql_query($SQLString,$dbcoonect);***

echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>\n";
    echo "<tr><th bgcolor=gray>Id</th><th bgcolor=gray>Name</th></tr>\n";
    while (($Row = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<tr><td bgcolor=tan>{$Row[0]}</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=tan>{$Row[1]}</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>

 </body>
 </html>
```